# Azure AAD and Graph API: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation while assigning Licenses

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to assign license to user using graph API but receiving "insufficient privileges to complete the operation. graph api" error even I have "Directory.ReadWrite.All" permission in Azure AD app.[Azure App permission screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoVNt.png)
struggling to get over it.

Comment: How did you get the access token to call this api? You can check the permissions by decoding the access token. https://jwt.io/

Comment: I did check on jwt.io I am getting scope as "scp": "Directory.ReadWrite.All User.Read profile openid" . Can you please confirm if it is coming correctly.

Comment: How did you get the access token? Can you paste the request here?

Comment: var graphScopes= { 
 scopes:["Directory.ReadWrite.All"]
 };

var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);


myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(graphScopes).then(function (tokenResponse) {
 alert(tokenResponse.accessToken); 
});

Comment: Why you have delegated and application permission for "Directory.ReadWrite.All"? They have different concepts and you might be getting confused. Are you signing in as a Global Admin user?

Comment: If you're assigning licenses using Graph API calls from your API, that means a logged in user isn't present and that requires that you add a permission to your API app registration in Azure Portal for Application Permissions for the scope "Directory.ReadWrite.All", here's how you do that. 

Go to your app registration for the API making the Graph API calls, select "API Permissions" > "Add a Permission" > "Microsoft APIs" > "Microsoft Graph" > "Application Permissions" > search Directory - Check Directory.ReadWrite.All > Add Permissions, now request an access token with that scope and use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're assigning licenses using Graph API calls from your API, that means a logged in user isn't present and that requires that you add a permission to your API app registration in Azure Portal for Application Permissions for the scope "Directory.ReadWrite.All", here's how you do that.

Go to your app registration for the API making the Graph API calls, select *"API Permissions" > "Add a Permission" > "Microsoft APIs" > "Microsoft Graph" > "Application Permissions" > search Directory - Check Directory.ReadWrite.All > Add Permissions*, now request an access token with that scope and use it.